# refactor LINQ function

Tags: c#, linq

How could I refactor this function so it could take any many to many parameters?

Program has many to many parameters as in Age, Color, etc...

So I have this function:

```
public int GetAgesOnProgram(IEnumerable<Program> ProgramList)
{
    return (from x in ProgramList
        where x.Ages.Any()
        select x.Ages).Count();
}
```

but I also need this one:

```
public int GetColorsOnProgram(IEnumerable<Program> ProgramList)
{
    return (from x in ProgramList
        where x.Colors.Any()
        select x.Colors).Count();
}
```

As I have up to 10 many to many relationships in Program, I guess it makes sense to have a single function that handles that?

EDIT:
How could I return the Age or Color List, rather than an int as in:

```
public IEnumerable<Color> GetColorsOnProgram(IEnumerable<Program> ProgramList)
{
    return (from x in ProgramList
        where x.Colors.Any()
        select x.Colors);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your function to:

```
public int GetCountOnProgram(IEnumerable<Program> ProgramList, Func<Program,bool> whereClause)
{
    return ProgramList.Where(whereClause).Count();
}
```

And then call it with:

```
GetCountOnProgram(programList, x => x.Ages.Any());
```

Comment: Shouldnt that method be renamed `GetCountOnProgram(..)` as its no longer just getting Ages?

Answer (score 3):

Just call `programList.Count(p => p.Ages.Any())`, `programList.Count(p => p.Colors.Any())` etc.

For your edit, if you want a single list of all the colors (or whatever) in any of your programs, you want `programList.SelectMany(p => p.Colors)`, possibly followed by `.Distinct()`.

Comment: Also, thanks - until now I didn't realize `Count` had an overload that took a predicate.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Wouter's correct answer, and in answer to your edit, you could add a method like:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetItemsOnProgram<T>(IEnumerable<ProgramItem> ProgramList, Func<ProgramItem,IEnumerable<T>> selectClause)
{
    return ProgramList.SelectMany(selectClause);
}
```

And then use it like:

```
GetItemsOnProgram(programList, x => x.Ages);
```

To get a list of all the ages in all the programs. This will not be a distinct list, but you can alsways tag a `Distinct()` on the end - albeit you may need to provide a `Comparer` to tell it how to make items distinct. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436.aspx) for documentation.